ISV App using SSO with Salesforce as Identity Provider - Where is it best to set up the SAML configuration?
We have an ISV app that allows our customers to use SSO - with Salesforce as the Identity Provider (IdP). To manage the SAML settings, we’ve configured a Connected App in our org. We have a 2GP package that deploys some custom objects which our app writes to.

Do we need to include the Connected App in our package so that it is installed on another org when we install our app?
If the Connected App is installed in our main org, can users from multiple customer domains/ sandboxes still authenticate using the same SAML settings?
Are there any best practices for managing Connected Apps in this scenario (e.g., making sure the solution works well for many different customer orgs)?

We have got the solution to work with 1. but according to this answer https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/367230/123311 it seems like 2 is an option (and one that we prefer but don't really understand how it would work in our case)

I can't respond on the SSO part as I have not set that up. Note that there is the new External Client Apps - though I understand these do not support SAML.
